# I'm trying to use \begin{align*}\end{align*} then some text and \begin{align*}\end{align*} again. But I want them both aligned*

Tags: align

[image]

How did they align the two sets of alignments over the word "and". I have looked for week for the answer to this problem. If someone sees it somewhere, I shall delete mine.
Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `amsmath` package and the `\intertext` command, as in:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  a&=b
     \intertext{and}
  c&=d
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OH MY! Thank you. I'm so glad you answer 1st so I didn't get some complicated macro solution.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: How? It won't let me upvote because I'm a newbie. Is there another way?

Comment: I said nothing about upvoting me. I wrote about accepteing my answer, which you can do by clicking on the ✓ sign.